# python not recognizing - sign in file path

Tags: python, filepath

I have a path like this to play an mp3 file using python:

`"C:\\Users\\x\\OneDrive - y\\Desktop\\Python\\play.mp3"`

It gives an error message of  `"Cannot specify extra characters after a string enclosed in quotation marks".` How can it be fixed? How to make sure that it recognizes the - sign in the file path?

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound("C:\\Users\\x\\OneDrive - y\\Desktop\\Python\\play.mp3)
```

Comment: Seriously? Can't you see the missing `"` at the end?

Comment: See the error message. I forgot to add the " at the end here but it is there in my source code.

Comment: First, edit your question. Correct your mistake in the question. Also a suggestion, sometimes the whitespace may result in a problem so try to just rename this section "\\OneDrive - y\\" to something like "\\OneDrive_y\\".

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, it seems you're missing a quote at the very end of the file path:

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound("C:\\Users\\x\\OneDrive - y\\Desktop\\Python\\play.mp3") # <-- here
```

Comment: Sorry, while pasting the code, the end quote got removed. It is there in my code already and I still see the error. from playsound import playsound
playsound("C:\\Users\\x\\OneDrive - y\\Desktop\\Python\\play.mp3"). The error is: Cannot specify extra characters after a string enclosed in quotation marks which I think is coming due to - sign after OneDrive.